# Android 4: Failed resolving class from org.simalliance.openmobileapi package

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, noclassdeffounderror

I'm working on application which make use of the org.simalliance.openmobileapi API to use the Secure element communication.

The application is Native that is the main Activity call a JNI library to operate. The JNI library use the JNI Method to call functions of the org.simalliance.openmobileapi package.

The API level is 8 as write in the mainfest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

The application work fine with Android 2.3.6 but when i try to launch the application from Android 4.0.4 or later the application can't find the SEService class of the org.simalliance.openmobileapi. Useful log are:

```
09-20 11:00:48.509: I/dalvikvm(1104): Failed resolving Lpkg/wrapper/SecureChannel; interface 203 'Lorg/simalliance/openmobileapi/SEService$CallBack;'
09-20 11:00:48.509: W/dalvikvm(1104): Link of class 'Lpkg/wrapper/SecureChannel;' failed
01-01 22:08:33.460: I/dalvikvm(10881): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.simalliance.openmobileapi.SEService$1
```

The class SecureChannel is a Java class that is called by the JNI to operate over the Secure Element and is contained in a jar that is "dexed" at compiling time with the rest of the project.

The package org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar is contained in the /system/framework folder in both version of Android:

On Android 2.3.6

```
-rw-r--r-- root     root        29148 2012-11-15 11:24 org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar
```

On Android 4.0.4

```
-rw-r--r-- root     root          313 2012-06-11 15:49 org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar
-rw-r--r-- root     root        24864 2012-06-11 15:49 org.simalliance.openmobileapi.odex
```

The only difference i see is the odex file in the Android 4.0.4 OS. 
Is there a way to include the classpath or the reference to a package contained in the /system/framework folder ?

Answer (score 3):

I've found a clean solution to this problem.

Instead of saying to the compiler that you want to compile the library into your application, just say that the library is provided for your application and everything will works fine.

In my case I use Gradle with Android studio.

So I just extract the .jar file from the downloaded add-on in my SDK path:

> sdk\add-ons\addon-open_mobile_api-giesecke_devrient_gmbh-18\libs

And placed it in my application libs folder.
Then in my build.gradle file I replaced :

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar')
}
```

with this :

```
dependencies {
    provided files('libs/org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar')
}
```

And now everything works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my configure in Android Studio

in app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], exclude: ['org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    provided files('libs/org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar')
}
```

in AndroidManifest.xml ,turning it true or false depends on you

```
    <uses-library
        android:name="org.simalliance.openmobileapi"
        android:required="false" />
```

and in /system/framwork/, "org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar" is required or an exception will throw up.

Comment: (Since those were deprecated the dependencies would now be `implementation` and `compileOnly` as per https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem putting on **src/** folder of my project the source contained in this package:

http://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/downloads/detail?name=MSC%20Smartcard%20Service%203.0.tar.gz&can=2&q=

More precisely the source in the package **com.mobilesecuritycard.openmobileapi.jar** which is the new version of the seek-for-android library made to replace the old package **org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar**.

I had to rename all the reference to the package from **com.mobilesecuritycard** to **org.simalliance** because the SecureChannel class was written with the old package so the old package name must be used.

Comment: Thx for sharing this, I am actually facing the same issue (but it works when I use the Giesecke & Devrient GmbH:Open Mobile API:18 build SDK version String instead of 18), I will try your solution. Did you manage doing the same thing with SmartCard API v.3.0.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

In android manifest don't forget add:

```
<application
        android:name=....
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:allowBackup = "true" >

        <!-- support USIM -->
        <uses-library
                android:name="org.simalliance.openmobileapi"
                android:required="false"/>
```